# Problem with displaying Office 365 within Salesforce frame

Tags: office-365

When I tried to use a web tab or a custom link with a custom component to display the Office 365 page, I'm directed to a new page with no headers and side menu. I need the page to be displayed within salesforce with headers and side menu. How can I achieve this. There is a checked option in click jack for non-salesforce pages which I have problem in un checking it.

Answer (score 0):

To disable clickjack protection on salesforce pages, you'll need to contact salesforce support.

> In the Spring ’14 release, the ability to disable clickjack protection from the Session Settings page will be removed, so you’ll have to contact salesforce.com Customer Support if you need to disable it. However, disabling clickjack protection is not recommended.

You can read more in the [Spring '14 Patch Notes.](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter14/release-notes/rn_186_forcecom_cruc_setup_pages.htm)